# Keyboard Shortcuts Not Working in Visual Studio 2013's Find in Files dialog?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I usually access Visual Studio's Find in Files feature with Ctrl-Shift-F, type in what I'm after and press enter.

Everything is working, I can type what I want to find, Ctrl-A will select all text, arrow keys will navigate within the Find What text control only the enter key press does nothing. The dialog still has focus, just nothing happens.

The accelerator keys that are marked on the various buttons also do not do what I expect. Alt-P will open the Project menu, Alt-F the File menu, Alt-A nothing. When the Find in Files dialog is focussed I expect the Find Previous, Find Next or Find All actions to be performed.

The tab key also does not change focus from one control to another while in that dialog.

The escape key will kill the focus in that dialog and return focus back to the file that I have open in the text editor as expected.

I have tried using the Reset button under Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard to no avail.

I am using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Update 4 on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: I am having the same problems, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Resharper, after applying R# keyboard scheme, it will add it's keyboard shortcuts. For example, it adds Alf+F shortcut in Text Editor scope.

Setting your keyboard shortcut in Global scope is not enough if same keyboard shortcut is set by R# for Text Editor.
To override R# shortcut in Global scope, make sure you delete R# shortcut setting in VS keyboard settings modal dialog.

Rarely, strange keyboard shortcut behavior could be also caused by non-US keyboard setting. If you are using non-English keyboard set in Windows Control Panel settings, try this solution:

1. Set keyboard layout to US
2. Reset keyboard shortcuts in VS under Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard
3. Assign your shortcuts (e.g. Alt-F)
4. Set keyboard to your local layout